# Kotlin type system - how to "add" a property to subclasses of two related classes

Tags: kotlin

I have two library classes, `Item` and `ItemFood : Item` (that is derived from `Item`), and a library function `registerItem(item: Item, name: String)`. I cannot modify them.

I have two of my own classes (`ItemKey : Item` and `ItemBerry : ItemFood`) that are derived from the library classes.

What I want is to store the `name: String` property in my classes `ItemKey` and `ItemBerry` and make them "count" as a `NamedItem`, so I can write a function like so:

```
fun registerNamedItem(namedItem: NamedItem) {
    registerItem(namedItem, namedItem.name)
}
```

I cannot just make a class like so: `class NamedItem(val name: String) : Item` and derive my classes from it, because sometimes I need to derive my classes from `ItemFood`, not from `Item`.

I don't want to make a class wrapper like `class NamedItem(val item: Item, val name: String)`, because then every time I want to get the "underlying" `Item` I will need to manually get the `item` property: `registerItem(namedItem.item, namedItem.name)`, and this is ugly.

I cannot use an `interface INamedItem { val name: String }` and implement this interface in `ItemKey` and `ItemBerry`, because then I will need to write a function in this way:

```
fun registerNamedItem(item: Item, namedItem: INamedItem) {
    registerItem(item, namedItem.name)
}
```

, and it is not an improvement at all.

Is there some kind of advanced technique - using an interface, delegation, generic, whatever - so I can implement the `registerNamedItem` function like I want it - passing to the `registerItem(item: Item, name: String)` an instance of the `NamedItem` as the first parameter and the `namedItem.name` as the second parameter?

Comment: Is `Item` a class or an interface?

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance. "I don't want to make a class wrapper because then every time I want to get the underlying Item this is ugly" This is not a valid argument, especially in Kotlin where you have builtin implementation-by-delegation support.

Comment: In fact, your case is exactly one of the main reasons why we don't like inheritance.

Comment: 2Alexey Romanov: `Item` is a class, and has a derived class `ItemFood`

Comment: 2SOFe: how can I leverage the delegation to remove the uglyness of using `namedItem.item` in the function? Also, the framework I work in forces me to subclass `Item`/`ItemFood` to add new kinds of items, so I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could use interface just for that:

```
fun main() {
    registerNamedItem(ItemKey("item_key"))
    registerNamedItem(ItemBerry("item_berry"))
}

// Cannot change this
open class Item

// Cannot change this
open class ItemFood : Item()

// This is your class
class ItemKey(override val name: String) : NamedItem()

// This is also your class
class ItemBerry(override val name: String) : NamedFoodItem()

// This is the property you would like to enforce
interface INamedItem {
    val name: String
}

// Since Item and ItemFood are concrete classes, you don't have much choice there
abstract class NamedItem : Item(), INamedItem    
abstract class NamedFoodItem : ItemFood(), INamedItem

// Adapter pattern
fun registerNamedItem(namedItem: NamedFoodItem) {
    registerItem(namedItem, namedItem.name)
}

// Adapter pattern
fun registerNamedItem(namedItem: NamedItem) {
    registerItem(namedItem, namedItem.name)
}

fun registerItem(namedItem: Item, name: String) {
    println("Item $namedItem registered with $name")
}
```

Delegation won't work in your case, since from your example, `Item` is a class, and you can only delegate to interfaces.

Comment: The problem is that the `registerItem` framework function expects an `Item`, not a `NamedItem`, so you cannot give it a variable of the type `NamedItem`

Comment: Remember, I don't have your code, nor do I know what "framework" you're working with. Updated my example. But maybe you're just better off with reflection, actually.